# How to retrieve an array data inside an array from firebase database: Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON data structure in Firebase database:

```
familylist
     |- 0
        |--children
        |   |-- 0:"AAA"
        |   |-- 1:"BBB"
        |-- code: "2222"
        |-- family: "SWE"
        |-- fatherName: "ABC"
        |-- motherName: "XYZ"
     |- 1
        |--children
        |   |-- 0:"XXX"
        |   |-- 1:"YYY"
        |-- code: "3333"
        |-- family: "ABC"
        |-- fatherName: "ERT"
        |-- motherName: "XTS"
```

I'm able to pull up all the fields except `children` from the JSON Tree. Can anyone suggest me how to retrieve the data from `children` ?

This is my code for retrieving all the fields from firebase database except children. What can be done to this code in order to retrieve the `children` values as well ? I'm not able to figure out.

```
familyListReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String key = (String) ds.getKey();
      Log.d(TAG, "Key" + key);
      DatabaseReference keyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist").child(key);
      Log.d(TAG, "Key reference: " + keyReference);
      keyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          String code = dataSnapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
          String family = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue(String.class);
          String father = dataSnapshot.child("fatherName").getValue(String.class);
          String mother = dataSnapshot.child("motherName").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
        }
      }); // [End of keyReference]

    } // END of for Loop
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
  }
}); // [End of familyListDatabaseReference]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `children` is a list, you're probably looking for:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child("children").getChildren()) {
    System.out.println(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
  }
}
```

Note that the Firebase documentation recommends against using arrays for such lists, such as in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Instead it recommends [using `push()` to populate lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Comment: Perfect and flawless! Actually, I've imported an existing JSON file to firebase database and from there pulling up the data from Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines of code in your `onDataChange()` method, after the declartation of those 4 strings:

```
      String code = dataSnapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
      String family = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue(String.class);
      String father = dataSnapshot.child("fatherName").getValue(String.class);
      String mother = dataSnapshot.child("motherName").getValue(String.class);
      for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("children").getChildren()) {
          Log.d("TAG", ds.getValue(String.class));
      }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In other nodes, I have 3 children. I can't hard code like this manually right?

Comment: I didn't know, and yes, you're right but i saw only 2 childrens in each node in your above example. So in order to solve this, please add those lines suggested by Frank van Puffelen.

Comment: Great! Worked for me!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you actually don't know about how many children you have, I think my solution is better then the one previously suggested by another user.

```
List<String> children = dataSnapshot.child("children").getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>(){});
```